# To send get request to Web API from Java Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, asp.net-web-api2, servlet-filters, spotfire

**Common question**

Is is possible to send get reguest from Java servlet's `doGet` method ? I need to check some "ticket" against my Web API .NET service, so can I call to this service from my custom servlet in the `doGet` method ?

```
public class IdentityProviderServlet extends HttpServlet {
...
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
...
// make request to Web API and save received user name to response
...
}
```

**Details**

We have web-app (.NET, MVC5) that is used TIBCO Spotfire 7.0 as engine of analysis reports. 
To allow our users to see reports inside web-app we use Spotfire WebPlayer (IIS web app) and JavaScript API. We authenticate our users in web app and then they are allowed to get request to WebPlayer leveraging JS API. In order to use already authenticated users we implemented custom authentication at WebPlayer based on keys-tickets as described [here](http://stn.spotfire.com/stn/Tasks/ImplementingCustomAuthentication.aspx). Thus we created .NET assembly that is loaded by Spotfire WebPlayer and calls overridden function. In this function we call Web API service to validate user and get valid spotfire username, then I create `IIdentity` with received username. 
When new version of TIBCO Spotfire 7.5 released we discovered that they [removed](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire_server/7.5.0/doc/html/TIB_sfire_server_tsas_admin_help/GUID-03FD5CD2-103C-444B-BE23-B1711C8797A8.html) support of custom authentication, because they [changed](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire_server/7.5.0/doc/html/TIB_sfire_server_tsas_admin_help/GUID-24E8A46B-4BB5-4D8C-8F24-FB8D77E8EC63.html) architecture and now they support "[external authentication](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire_server/7.5.0/doc/html/TIB_sfire_server_tsas_admin_help/GUID-0E4154FC-97AE-43D4-8EBF-A9BD9380D83C.html)". This approach could be implemented as as Java servlet that is used to authenticate user and then spotfire:

> Retrieves the user name from the getUserPrincipal() method of
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest

All this forced us to re-write our logic in Java. However we don't want to change overall workflow of our authentication and we want to stick to already working ticketing schema. I'm new to Java servlets, so my goal to implement the same authentication based on servlet. They have [example](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire_server/7.5.0/doc/api/TIB_sfire_server_Custom_Authentication_Filter_API_Reference/javadoc/index.html) where servlet class has  methods `doGet` and `doPost` ([link to zip with example](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire_server/7.5.0/doc/api/TIB_sfire_server_Custom_Authentication_Filter_API_Examples.zip)). My assumption here that I can implement my own `doGet` and send request to Web API to validate ticket and get back username.

Does it make sense ?

Comment: Just a quick comment - in 7.6 a new [CustomAuthenticator](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire_server/7.6.0/doc/api/TIB_sfire_server_Server_Platform_API_Reference/platform/com/spotfire/server/security/CustomAuthenticator.html) API was added to the Spotfire Server that probably is a bit easier to implement (although your original question is still relevant).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the library [Apache HTTP Components](http://hc.apache.org)

Short example for `doGet()` (I didn't compile it):

```
import org.apache.http.*;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.*;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.http.entity.InputStreamEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
{
   String url="http://your.server.com/path/to/app?par1=yxc&par2=abc");
   HttpGet get=new HttpGet(url);
   httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
   // optional configuration
   RequestConfig config=RequestConfig.custom().setSocketTimeout(socketTimeoutSec * 1000).build();
    // more configuration

    get.setConfig(config);

    CloseableHttpResponse internResponse = httpClient.execute(get);

    int internResponseStatus = internResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

    InputStream respIn = internResponseEntity.getContent();
    String contentType = internResponseEntity.getContentType().getValue();

    // consume the response
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I haven't compiled it yet too, but, at least, you gave direction where to look.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I end up with this code. I implemented simple filter instead of servlet.

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import java.io.*;
import org.json.*;

public class Authenticator implements IAuthenticator {

    @Override
    public IIdentity doAuthentication(String pathToAuthIdentity) throws IOException {
        try {
            // Create an instance of HttpClient.
            HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();

            // Create a method instance.
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(pathToAuthIdentity);

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(get);

            int internResponseStatus = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if(200 == internResponseStatus)
            {
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

                StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
                String line = "";
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }

                String userName = null;
                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result.toString());
                    userName = obj.getString("SpotfireUser");
                } catch (JSONException ex) {
                }
                return new Identity(userName);                
            }else
            {
                return new AIdentity(null);                
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw ex;
        } 
    }

    public class AIdentity implements IIdentity
    {
        private final String UserName;
        public AIdentity(String userName)
        {
            this.UserName = userName;
        }
        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return UserName;
        }

    }
}
```

And that's how I use this class

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.security.Principal;
    import javax.servlet.http.*;
    import javax.servlet.Filter;
    import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
    import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
    import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;


    public class SpotfireAuthFilter implements Filter {

        private static final String AUTHENTICATION_SERVICE_URL_PARAM = "AUTHENTICATION_SERVICE_URL";
        private static final String COOKIE_NAME_PARAM = "COOKIE_NAME";



        private ServletContext context;    
        private String[] SpotfireTicketNames = null;
        private String[] AuthServiceBaseURLs = null;

        private IAuthenticator AuthService;

        @Override
        public void init(FilterConfig fc) throws ServletException {
            context = fc.getServletContext();

            if(null == fc.getInitParameter(AUTHENTICATION_SERVICE_URL_PARAM) 
                || null == fc.getInitParameter(COOKIE_NAME_PARAM) )
            {
                throw new ServletException("Can't read filter initial parameters");
            }

            AuthServiceBaseURLs = fc.getInitParameter(AUTHENTICATION_SERVICE_URL_PARAM).split(",");
            SpotfireTicketNames = fc.getInitParameter(COOKIE_NAME_PARAM).split(",");
            AuthService = new Authenticator();

            if(SpotfireTicketNames.length != AuthServiceBaseURLs.length)
            {
                throw new ServletException(
                        String.format("Count of '%s' parameter don't equal '%s' parameter", 
                                COOKIE_NAME_PARAM, 
                                AUTHENTICATION_SERVICE_URL_PARAM));
            }

        }

        @Override
        public final void doFilter(
                ServletRequest servletRequest,
                ServletResponse servletResponse,
                FilterChain chain)  throws ServletException 
        {
            final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
            final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

            try 
            {
                doFilter(request, response, chain);
            } 
            catch (IOException | RuntimeException e) 
            {
              // Not possible to authenticate, return a 401 Unauthorized status code without any WWW-Authenticate header

              sendError(response, 401, "Unauthorized");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void destroy() {
         // do nothing   
        }

        private void doFilter(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException 
        {

            String url = getAuthServiceURL(request);
            if(null != url)           
            {


                IIdentity identity = AuthService.doAuthentication(url);
                if(null != identity)
                {
                    String userName = identity.getName();
                    if(null != userName && !userName.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                    {
                        Principal principal = createPrincipal(userName);

                        // Pass on the request to the filter chain and the authentication framework
                        // should pick up this priincipal and authenticate user
                        chain.doFilter(new WrappedHttpServletRequest(request, principal), response);


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new IOException("Authentication failed");
                    }
                }else
                {
                    throw new IOException("Can't authenticate user by url " + url);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new IOException("Can't find ticket to authenticate user.");
            }

            // Done!
            return;
        }

        private void sendError(HttpServletResponse response, int statusCode, String message) {
            try {
              response.sendError(statusCode, message);
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
        }

        private String getAuthServiceURL(HttpServletRequest request) {

            Cookie[] cookies  = request.getCookies();
            for(int i =0; i< cookies.length; ++i)
            {
                for(int j =0; j< SpotfireTicketNames.length; ++j)
                {
                    if(cookies[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase(SpotfireTicketNames[j]))
                    {
                        return String.format(AuthServiceBaseURLs[j], cookies[i].getValue());
                    }    
                }
            }
            return null;
        }


    private Principal createPrincipal(String username) 
    {

        // check does username contain domain/email/display name 
        return new APrincipal(username);
    }



    /**
     * A wrapper for {@link HttpServletRequest} objects.
     */
    private static class WrappedHttpServletRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

      private final Principal principal;

      public WrappedHttpServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request, Principal principal) {
        super(request);
        this.principal = principal;
      }

      @Override
      public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
        return this.principal;
      }

    } // WrappedHttpServletRequest
  }


    public class APrincipal implements Principal {
        private final String _username;

        public APrincipal(String username) {
           _username = username;
        }

        @Override
        public String getName() {
         return _username;   
        }

    }
```

And these initial parameters

[image: initial parameters]

Comment: I will follow what did you do with filter instead of servlet. does this filter works as SSO, so no need to implement another SSO when need to open webplayer from some portal. Thanks in advance.