# Java Servlet Requesting Data From Local Service

Tags: java, servlets

In a Java `HttpServlet`, is it possible to request data from another local service using the original request's header information without necessarily forwarding?

For example, I have `FooBar.java`:

```
// Handles the url at /foo/bar and can be accessed at http://localhost/foo/bar
public class FooBar extends HttpServlet
{
   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
   {
      Object data = ...                             // 1. Retrieve data at http://localhost/foo/baz utilizing the current request's header
      Object newData = doSomething(data);           // 2. Process the data
      response.getWriter().write(newData.toString); // 3. Return the processed data
   }

   private Object doSomething(Object data)
   {
      // Perform some business logic
   }
}
```

Step 1 is the issue here. The purpose of this is that I want to be able to perform some sort of logic on the data before returning it in full, but don't necessarily have access do make the changes on the handler at `/foo/baz` do to the propriety nature of things.

Comment: Create new HttpGet, populate it with headers information from original request and then send to http://localhost/foo/baz ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `HttpURLConnection` and altering the header to include a property from the original request, I was able to get a `BufferedReader` from the HTTP request:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
   // Step 1
   String serverName = request.getLocalName();
   String contextPath = request.getContextPath();

   URL url = new URL("https://" + serverName + contextPath + "/baz");
   HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   connection.setRequestProperty("Key Header", request.getHeader("Key Header"));

   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

   // Step 2
   ... // Do something with the data from the reader

   // Step 3
   ... // Write the data back using the response
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this answer of me to create a HTTP Request: [send get request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36083183/1988304)

In addition, it may be necessary to copy the request header with some care:

```
private static final Set forbiddenCopyHeaders = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{
        "connection"
        , "transfer-encoding"
        , "content-length"    // POST kann zu Status 500 führen, wenn die content-length kopiert wird
        , "via"
        , "x-forwarded-for"
        , "x-forwarded-host"
        , "x-forwarded-server"
}));

private void copyRequestHeaders(HttpServletRequest customerRequest, HttpRequestBase internRequest) throws
        HttpException
{

    Enumeration<String> headerNames = customerRequest.getHeaderNames();
    String connectionHeader = customerRequest.getHeader("connection");

    while (headerNames.hasMoreElements())
    {
        String headerName = headerNames.nextElement();

        boolean copyAllowed = !forbiddenCopyHeaders.contains(headerName.toLowerCase()) &&
                !StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(connectionHeader, headerName);

        if (copyAllowed)
        {
            Enumeration<String> values = customerRequest.getHeaders(headerName);
            while (values.hasMoreElements())
            {
                internRequest.addHeader(headerName, values.nextElement());
            }
        }
    }

    setProxySpecificRequestHeaders(customerRequest, internRequest);
}


private void setProxySpecificRequestHeaders(HttpServletRequest customerRequest,
                                            HttpRequestBase internRequest) throws HttpException
{
    String serverHostName = "doorman";
    try
    {
        serverHostName = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e)
    {
        logger.error("Couldn't get the hostname needed for headers x-forwarded-server and Via", e);
    }

    String originalVia = customerRequest.getHeader("via");
    StringBuilder via = new StringBuilder("");
    if (originalVia != null)
    {
        if (originalVia.contains(serverHostName))
        {
            logger.error("This proxy has already handled the Request, will abort.");
            throw new HttpException("Request has a cyclic dependency on this proxy.");
        }
        else
        {
            via.append(originalVia).append(", ");
        }
    }
    via.append(customerRequest.getProtocol()).append(" ").append(serverHostName);

    internRequest.addHeader("via", via.toString());
    internRequest.addHeader("x-forwarded-for", customerRequest.getRemoteAddr());
    internRequest.addHeader("x-forwarded-host", customerRequest.getServerName());
    internRequest.addHeader("x-forwarded-server", serverHostName);

    internRequest.addHeader("accept-encoding", "");
}
```

Comment: I realized I only had to copy one specific property of the header. I do have a question though: How is the `HttpGet` and `HttpClient` method of doing a `GET` request different from `HttpsURLConnection`? I'll post my solution in a second here, but that's what I came up with.

Comment: @Aetylus - I've used the classes from Apache HTTP Components because they provide some extra features for handling the body of a request/response. Perhaps `HttpsUrlConnection` is sufficient for your task. I'll add the code of the method `setProxySpecificRequestHeaders()` to my answer.