# TIBCO Spotfire 7.8 CustomAuthenticator

Tags: spotfire

In new TIBCO Spotfire 7.8 released we discovered that Authentication filter is deprecated and we have to either use CustomAuthenticator, CustomWebAuthenticator or Custom Login Page.

According to them, I have to make more changes in our java utility jar file. However, I don't want to changes overall workflow of our authentication filter logic and we want to use our already cookie mechanism. The goal is to use the CustomAuthenticator instead of the servlet that I am using in authentication filter.

I have configured the TIBCO Spotfire External authentication as CustomAuthenticator

[External Authentication Config Tool Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYFbz.png)

and updated my java logic as per the information available at

https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire_server/7.6.0/doc/api/TIB_sfire_server_Server_Platform_API_Reference/platform/com/spotfire/server/security/CustomAuthenticator.html

but this information is not too much use to identify what level of changes I need to make in my application as well as in Java logic.

Any help?

I have also found a link that is for authentication filter and the similar logic I have written in my java utility, that I need to modify with CustomAuthenticator.

[To send get request to Web API from Java Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36077981/to-send-get-request-to-web-api-from-java-servlet/36083183)